# generate image from codeigniter loaded view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to generate an image from my existing codeigniters view. I use codeigniter 3.
 This is my code:

```
$invoice = $this->load->view('member/purchase_invoice',$data,true);
```

I want to make an image file from `$invoice`, then save to server directory, so users can download it. I use the generated image to make click to download button, so I don't want to display it.

Comment: Why you are not just working with PDF library?

Comment: hello @MD.JubairMizan, I already try some PDF library like mpdf and dompdf, but I am looking for directly convert solution that convert the view to image not convert  to PDF file first

Comment: Are you displaying that page to user?. If so, then you can capture the screen, save as image and upload to server, using JavaScript.

Comment: hy @shashidhara, I use the generated image to make click to download button, so I don't want to display it

Comment: Question is quite unclear, can you explain the issue with code snippet.

Comment: @Shashidhara , I do not need to explain it with code snippet. I solved it yesterday by using PhantomMagick (https://github.com/anam-hossain/phantommagick)

Comment: Great. I appreciate your effort :-)

Comment: @Shashidhara ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by using PhantomMagick (github.com/anam-hossain/phantommagick)